# I have ImageView & TextView inside RelativeLayout. Now I go to put Text on that bitmap(ImageView)?

Tags: android, bitmap

> after of this i want to capture all the edited properties with text & store as bitmap
>
> how can I do that... ???

Answer (score 1):

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="500dp"
    android:layout_height="500dp"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:src="@android:drawable/sym_def_app_icon" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="17dp"
    android:text="Enter Your Text Here" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
yourRelativeLayout.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
yourRelativeLayout.buildDrawingCache();
Bitmap bm = yourRelativeLayout.getDrawingCache();
```

This way you can create bitmap of any view you want.